# I am reading a directory and i want to find all details whether it is file or folder and when it is been created

Tags: php

```
$records = array(); 
$dir = "./uploads/dms/";

if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            $record=array(); 
            $record['content']=$file;
            $records[]=(object)$record;
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}

foreach ($records as $record) {
    echo $record->content;
    var_dump(filetype($record->content));
}
```

This never tells me what type of content it is. whether it is file or folder why?

Comment: What does `var_dump(filetype($record->content));` output?

Comment: You need the full path to the file/directory. So try, var_dump(filetype($dir.$record->content));

This will give you file/dir, and not false on every record.

Comment: yes i need the full path. It is done. thanks user9189147